# Kineticjs on mobile setting 2 different width and sizes

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I've a really weird issue when setting the height and width on the Kinetic.Stage(). If I set the height to 300 each on the desktop I get:

```
<canvas width="300" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute;" height="300"></canvas>
```

but when I inspect it on a mobile device i get

```
<canvas width="600" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute;" height="600"></canvas>
```

Which throws the positioning all out. I'm wondering if anyone knows of this issue and if its something I'm missing.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: very odd, can you post a more complete version of your code?

Comment: looking through the source there seems to be window.devicePixelRatio which may no be set on every height and width. May raise with KineticJS on GitHub

Comment: again, can you post some of your code, outside of just the canvas tag?

Comment: This looks correct so far - the width and height are set differently from the width and height style in order to handle the device pixel ratio.  Can you tell me exactly what the problem is? i.e. what does "throws the positioning all out" exactly mean?